# How would Japanese clan leaders address one another aside from the title -dono?

Tags: suffixes

I'm writing a book where several Japanese clans interact with one another in both formal and non-formal settings. I was wondering a few things.

1. How did clan leaders greet one another? What would be the suffix attached to their name? Would they address them by family name or by a title?
2. Would there be a difference in respect when meeting/visiting on one of the clans' lands? Would the visitor have a different method of address then?

I know this is a bit of an odd thing to ask, but I want to ensure that my book is as accurate in all cultures involved. I want to minimize as many mistakes as possible to ensure that the audience will focus on the plot, not the mistakes.

Edit: The gist of my question is that, while I know that Japanese clan leaders were called ex. Asahi-dono as a title, how would someone of this same rank address them?

Comment: What kind of "clan" are you talking about? A yakuza clan? A historical [samurai clan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_clans)? Or something different?

Comment: A historical japanese clan.

Comment: What time period are you talking about?  Titles and honorifics and _yobi_ move around a lot over the course of time.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Toward the end of the samurai era. Canonically, this clan follows the last known general style of clan life, so the last known or later known titles would've been used.